# Vue - Accessing the Vue instance beforeEnter to access function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am having an issue accessing the 'Vue' in a `beforeEnter` function.

When a session has expired I have a small toast show that tells the user to login again.

When toast contains a button, which when clicked I'd like to trigger another modal to allow the user to login. This is contained in the 'Vue' as a sperte component.

How do I access the 'Vue' ('this') to trigger the modal?

I've tried; this.app and this.a.app - among others lists on SO and elsewhere, to to avail.

Thanks.

Route

```
     {
          path: "/dashboard",
          name: "dashboard",
          component: Dashboard,
          beforeEnter: protectedPage,
          meta: {
            title: "Dashboard"
          }
        },
```

Function

```
function protectedPage(to, from, next) {
    if (VueJwtDecode.decode(localStorage.token).exp < Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)) {
      localStorage.removeItem("token");
      Vue.toasted.show("The session has ended. Please login.", {
        theme: "toasted-primary",
        position: "top-center",
        duration: null,
        action: {
          text: "Login",
          onClick: (e, toastObject) => {
            // CODE HERE TO TRIGGER LOGIN MODAL
            next("/");
            toastObject.goAway(0);
          }
        }
      });
      Vue.toasted.hide();
      next("/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you can on a beforeEnter looking at the docs but you can achieve the same on a beforeRouteEnter inside the component itself. By passing a callback.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    getPost(to.params.id, (err, post) => {
      next(vm => vm.setData(err, post))
    })
  },
```